# Регулярное выражение. Вывод текста между двумя регулярными выражениями

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения, строки

есть код:

```
$text = " поле1 - значение
поле2: значение
поле3: значение
поле4: значение
поле2: значение";
```

я с помощью регулярки(в которой я покачто мало что понимаю) поделил на строки для упрощение поиска

```
$keywords = preg_split("/[\n,]+/", $test);
```

затем нахожу значение

```
$testText = preg_match('/поле2:/', $test, $match);
```

**Вопрос**
Как вывести всё между например "поле2" до "поле3". Учитывая что есть вероятность переноса строки.

Comment: `preg_match('/поле2:\K.*?(?=поле3:)/s', $test, $match); echo $match[0];`? https://3v4l.org/gvOrm, https://regex101.com/r/0bNgwF/1

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете использовать

```
'/поле2:\K.*?(?=поле3:)/su'
```

См. [пример работы выражения](https://regex101.com/r/0bNgwF/1).

Если нужно найти строку до `поле3:` или конца строки, используйте `'/поле2:\K.*?(?=поле3:|$)/su'`.

**Подробности**

- `поле2:` - строка `поле2:`
- `\K` - оператор, удаляющий весь текст из буфера текущего совпадения
- `.*?` - 0 и более любых символов (флаг `s` позволяет точке находить также переносы строки), как можно меньше
- `(?=поле3:|$)` - строка `поле3:` или конец строки.

Пример [работы кода в PHP](https://3v4l.org/o2lj4):

```php
$text = " поле1 - значение
поле2: значение
поле3: значение
поле4: значение
поле2: значение";
if (preg_match('/поле2:\K.*?(?=поле3:)/su', $text, $match)) {
  echo $match[0];
}
// => значение
```